# Django Application Wont Load User Uploaded Image

Tags: python, django

I used Django Admin to upload an image and I am trying to get it to display in a template. The `alt` text is displayed but I keep getting a `404` error for the image and it does not display. When I uploaded the image the path that it pulls in the template `media/images/mari-profile-pic.png` is valid and contains the image I am trying to display.

```
models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Image

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    imageModel = Image.objects.get(pk=1)
    return render(
        request,
        "SocialLinks/index.html",
        {
            "profile_pic_title":imageModel.title,
            "profile_pic":imageModel.image
        }
    )
```

```
index.html template

    <div id="profile">
        <img id="userPhoto" src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ profile_pic }}" alt="{{ profile_pic_title }}">
    </div>
```

```
settings.py

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I have tried removing and adding the `{% get_media_prefix %}` tag and the image still does not display.

Answer (score 0):

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'media_root')
```

your.html:

```
{% load static %}
```

To make the imgaes works add .url to be like this: {{ i.img.url }}, and go to the urls.py of the app, and add the following:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Call the templates and the statics from the (`PROJECTNAME/settings.py`) by add the following in the `TEMPLATES` `'DIRS'`:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'temp')],
```